# QGIS - How to display item info on popup with a click

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, popup, getfeatureinfo, display

I have many items on different shapefile (parks, railways, buses...). Every shape as a join with an attribute table and each table contains data by line.

How can I generate a pop-up by clicking on the item with the related info?

I believe I do not use actions because all data are loaded in the QGIS project (but I can also link data from external sources). I am not able how to set query to show only the info related to the click.

I use QGIS 2.8 on windows

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Identify Features** tool.

Excerpt from the [QGIS User Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify):

> The Identify tool allows you to interact with the map canvas and get information on features in a pop-up window. To identify features, use View ‣ Identify features or press Ctrl + Shift + I, or click on the mActionIdentify Identify features icon in the toolbar.
>
> If you click on several features, the Identify results dialog will list information about all the selected features. The first item is the number of the layer in the list of results, followed by the layer name. Then, its first child will be the name of a field with its value. The first field is the one selected in Properties ‣ Display. Finally, all information about the feature is displayed.

...

> At the bottom of the window, you have the Mode and View comboboxes. With the Mode combobox you can define the identify mode: ‘Current layer’, ‘Top down, stop at first’, ‘Top down’ and ‘Layer selection’. The View can be set as ‘Tree’, ‘Table’ and ‘Graph’.